# Retrieving unjoined/non-overlapping rows

Tags: mysql, database

I'm using the following query to join **Table_A** and **Table_B**:

```
select *
from Table_A a
join Table_B b on a.Country = b.Land and a.City = b.Town and A.Language = B.Spoken;
```

Is it possible to retrieve the rows in Table_A that was **not** joined? I need to know which rows that are overlapping, and which are not. Maybe there's a better solution than "join on" in this case?

---

**UPDATE WITH REAL DATA**

I'm using the following query to join the tables **schedulingErrorsProd** and **serviceProductions**:

```
select *
from schedulingErrorsProd a
join serviceProductions b on a.receiverid = b.logicalAdress_logicalAddress and a.tjanstekontrakt = b.serviceContract_namespace
where b.connectionPoint_id = 4;
```

Is it possible to retrieve the rows in **schedulingErrorsProd** that was not joined? I need to know which rows that are overlapping, and which are not. Maybe there's a better solution than "join on" in this case?

A picture of all tables/columns and their joining:
[image]

Comment: Not quite following, Here it looks like all you want to do is join. Is that not right?

Comment: I removed the image since it was confusing. I want to somehow see which rows that are joined by the query as well as those who aren't.

Comment: See my answer. This join includes both the rows that are joined, and those who are not. You can see which ones are not joined by the null in the first or the last column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is to show all joined records, and all records that have NOT been joined. An so called "Full outer join" that is not supported in MySQL officially.
Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vvcfn2nr7XNiPg9kNggXsd/1

```
CREATE TABLE table_a (
  continent varchar(50),
  country varchar(50),
  city varchar(50),
  language varchar(50)
);
INSERT INTO table_a (continent,country,city,language) VALUES ('Europe', 'Sweden', 'Stockholm', 'Swedish');
INSERT INTO table_a (continent,country,city,language) VALUES ('Asia', 'Russia', 'Moscow', 'Russian');
INSERT INTO table_a (continent,country,city,language) VALUES ('Europe', 'Norway', 'Oslo', 'Norwegian');

CREATE TABLE table_b (
  land varchar(50),
  town varchar(50),
  spoken varchar(50),
  currency varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO table_b (land,town,spoken,currency) VALUES ('Sweden', 'Stockholm', 'Swedish', 'Svensk Krona');
INSERT INTO table_b (land,town,spoken,currency) VALUES ('Finland', 'Helsinki', 'Finnish', 'Dunno');
INSERT INTO table_b (land,town,spoken,currency) VALUES ('Norway', 'Oslo', 'Norwegian', 'Norsk Krona');

SELECT a.continent, a.country, a.city, a.language, b.currency
FROM table_a as a
left join table_b as b 
on a.country = b.land and a.city = b.town and a.language = b.Spoken
union
SELECT 
a2.continent, 
case when a2.country is null then b2.land else a2.country end, 
case when a2.city is null then b2.town else a2.city end, 
case when a2.language is null then b2.spoken else a2.language end, 
b2.currency
FROM table_a as a2
right join table_b as b2 
on a2.country = b2.land and a2.city = b2.town and a2.language = b2.spoken
```

EDIT * Question updated *
This is the new code for the new question:

```
SELECT b.connectionPoint_id, a.timestamp, a.waypoint, a.senderid, a.receiverid, a.tjanstekontrakt, a.errorCode, a.time_producer, a.loglevel, a.loglevel, a.endpoint_url
FROM schedulingErrorsProd as a
left join serviceProductions as b 
on a.receiverid = b.logicalAdress_logicalAddress and a.tjanstekontrakt = b.serviceContract_namespace
and b.connectionPoint_id = 4;
```

Comment: Thanks! I had trouble converting this answer to my real data so I'll try to make another question.

Comment: @RawlandHustle Please post here when you have, and if I have time I will take a look!

Comment: I've posted a question with real data here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71786209/retrieving-joined-and-unjoined-rows

Comment: @RawlandHustle Saw that it was closed, could you put all information in an fiddle, and post it here? Include the tables and some example data, that is all.

Comment: @RawlandHustle check my fiddle in the response, and simply mimic what I did. Change the table names, columns and data!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243698/discussion-between-rawland-hustle-and-stoff).

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the rows of `serviceProductions` then you should use a `LEFT` join and the condition `b.connectionPoint_id = 4` in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM schedulingErrorsProd a LEFT JOIN serviceProductions b 
ON a.receiverid = b.logicalAdress_logicalAddress 
AND a.tjanstekontrakt = b.serviceContract_namespace
AND b.connectionPoint_id = 4;
```

The unmatched rows will have `null` in all the columns of the table `logicalAdress_logicalAddress`.

If you want only the unmatched rows of `serviceProductions` then you should add to the above query a `WHERE` clause that filters out the matched rows, like:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM schedulingErrorsProd a LEFT JOIN serviceProductions b 
ON a.receiverid = b.logicalAdress_logicalAddress 
AND a.tjanstekontrakt = b.serviceContract_namespace
AND b.connectionPoint_id = 4;
WHERE b.connectionPoint_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: This worked on my real data. Thank you!